# Make links in stylelint report in bash output clickable

Tags: bash, hyperlink, stylelint

I am using [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) and [eslint](https://eslint.org/) and I just mentioned that it is possible to click on a line in [eslint](https://eslint.org/) to directly open the file in my IDE and jump to that selected line.

[image: screenshot of eslint]

I was wondering if it is possible to add a similar feature to [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) since this is not possible by default:

[image: screenshot of stylelint]

I already tried to fix this, but I cannot find a track that feels good. Can you recommend a way to do this? Is this something that should be changed directly in the source code of [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) or should it be written as [plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins)? And if yes, is there any plugin that already modifies messages that I can use as example/reference? Or does this feature already exist and I was just not able to find out how to enable it?

Another idea of myself was to pipe/pass the output of `stylelint` to another script to then be able to use some regular expressions to replace the lines with hyperlinks like described in [Terminal - create hyperlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284476/terminal-create-hyperlinks), but I think there should be a less hacky way to resolve this.

Looking forward to some tips where I should dig deeper, thank you in advice!